# Dog (Canis lupus familiaris) MT gene annotations

Tags: sequence-annotation, ensembl

I have an RNA-Seq and scRNA-Seq dataset from dog samples and pseudo-aligned them to the dog reference transcriptome (Ensembl release 109). When filtering for mitochondrial gene percentage in scRNA-Seq I couldn't find the "MT" annotation in this new release. Does anyone have any information about this? Did they not include it or am I doing something wrong somewhere (the MT annotations are present in the CanFam3.1 genome built but not in the newer ones).
I could not find anything on the Ensembl release details or blog.

Thank you :)

This is a part of the code that I used to search for the mitochondrial genes:

```
searchFilterOptions(mart=ensembl_canis, filter="chromosome_name", pattern="MT")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no available mitochondrial sequence for the ROS_Cfam_1.0 assembly:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/datasets/genome/GCF_014441545.1/

Comment: Thank you for your reply Ben!